# Pass mock DOM event to directive handler without jQuery

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, mocking, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a very simple directive whose purpose is just to cancel the `dragstart` event:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  element.on('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })
}
```

How can I test this in a Jasmine test? I have the following test that attempts to spy on an Event object, and pass it to the handler:

```
var mockEvent; 

beforeEach(function() {
  mockEvent = new Event('dragstart');
  spyOn(mockEvent,'preventDefault');
});

it('should call preventDefault', function () {
  element.triggerHandler('dragstart', mockEvent);
  expect(mockEvent.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But the test fails. You can [see this at this Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/RaNifv7e0m7zSPMJDgmP?p=preview). How can I test this (/refactor the directive to make it testable)?

Edit: Ideally without including jQuery.
Edit: changed tags

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the current stable version of Angular, 1.3.14, you can do this without jQuery by passing the event as the first and only parameter of `triggerHandler`, so instead of what was suggested in the question

```
element.triggerHandler('dragstart', new Event('dragstart'));
```

you can write

```
element.triggerHandler(new Event('dragstart'));
```

To add a spy on the `preventDefault` function, as per the original question, you can do the following

```
var mockEvent; 

beforeEach(function() {
  mockEvent = new Event('dragstart');
  spyOn(mockEvent, 'preventDefault');
});

it('should call preventDefault', function () {
  element.triggerHandler(mockEvent);
  expect(mockEvent.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

You can [see this working in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ewMLabYjq2Y7BcovkbEP?p=preview). You can alternatively just use a plain object with at least a `type` key, so in this case

```
mockEvent = {
  type: 'dragstart',
  preventDefault: jasmine.createSpy('preventdefault')
};
```

which can be seen [working in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F9CV1uQ3b4rLyuMhmm7T?p=preview)

I believe this was added to the 1.3 branch in [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/01d81cdab3dbbcb8b4204769eb5272096eb0837f).

Comment: Please edit your title or your answer to specify Angular. Others searching for vanilla JavaScript solutions are landing here.

Answer (score 11):

you may include jquery and create a jquery event object. this object can easly be passed:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  mockEvent = $.Event('dragstart');
  spyOn(mockEvent,'preventDefault');
});

it('should call preventDefault', function () {
  element.triggerHandler(mockEvent);
  expect(mockEvent.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

i have used this jquery version in your plunkr: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: I've added jQuery and changed the test at http://plnkr.co/edit/aRvgHQXPTCSvlXougxHX?p=preview , but the test is still failing.

Comment: element.triggerHandler(mockEvent);
not element.triggerHandler('dragstart' ,mockEvent);

Comment: Ah, that works, including changing `$.Event` to `new Event`, as can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/2LrrEBjVjftXH5ueprLI?p=preview. Is there a way to do this without jQuery?